# Kubernetes NFS: Using service name instead of hardcoded server IP address

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, service-name

I was able to get it working following NFS example in Kubernetes.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs

However, when I want to automate all the steps, I need to find the IP and update `nfs-pv.yaml` PV file with the hard coded IP address as mentioned in the example link page.

> Replace the invalid IP in the nfs PV. (In the future, we'll be able to
>   tie these together using the service names, but for now, you have to
>   hardcode the IP.)

Now, I wonder that **how can we tie these together using the services names**?

Or, **it is not possible** at the latest version of Kubernetes (as of today, the latest stable version is [v1.6.2](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases)) ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after I add **kube-dns** address to the each minion|node where **Kubernetes** is running. After login each minion, update **resolv.conf** file as the following;

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search openstacklocal localdomai
nameserver 10.0.0.10 # I added this line
nameserver 159.107.164.10
nameserver 153.88.112.200
....
```

I am not sure is it the best way but this works.

Any better solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use do this with the help of `kube-dns`, 
check whether it's service running or not,

`kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system`

and kube-dns pod also,

`kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system`

you have to add respected name-server according to kube-dns on each node in cluster,
For more troubleshooting, follow this document,
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Is it not same as below answer? Maybe you explained in a better way.